# I want to select the from values from database in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

Here is my code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->base_prefix . 'item WHERE uname = "'. $_POST['login_name'] . '" ';
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
foreach($result as $results) {
    $results->salt;
    $results->password;
  }
echo $sal->$results[0];
echo $pwd->$results[1];
```

Comment: code is ok, what is question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [`wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) docs and don't forget to [protect your query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks):

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "item"; 
$login_name = sanitize_user( $_POST['login_name'] ); //assuming you're dealing with username

$prepare = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE uname = %s", $login_name );

$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( $prepare );

//output results
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $myrows, true ) . '</pre>';
```